# How can I Use Consts from different files in React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Can you please tell me how to use consts from different JS files in React. I'm trying to calculate a total score of 4 different Quiz scores (Average).

Thank you !

I did try to export and import but didn't work.

Here is the code I'm working on for the first quiz :

```
const playerStatsEco = {
    ecoscore: null,
    numberOfQuestions: null,
    numberOfAnsweredQuestions: null,
    correctAnswers: null,
    wrongAnswers: null,
};

class playeco extends Component {

...

endGame = () => {
        alert('Le quiz est terminé ! لقد انتهى الاختبار');
        const { state } = this;
        playerStatsEco.ecoscore = state.ecoscore;
        playerStatsEco.numberOfQuestions = state.numberOfQuestions;
        playerStatsEco.numberOfAnsweredQuestions = state.correctAnswers + state.wrongAnswers;
        playerStatsEco.correctAnswers = state.correctAnswers;
        playerStatsEco.wrongAnswers = state.wrongAnswers;
    
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.history.push('/play/sum', playerStatsEco);
    }, 1000);
};
```

When I try to export the class, it works. But when I try to export the const as well using this line

```
export  {playeco, playerStatsEco};
```

This error happens :

Attempted import error: './components/quiz/playeco' does not contain a default export (imported as 'playeco').

Comment: just use export to export them and import them in the file you want to use them.........

Comment: @SR810 Thank you for your answer, but when I tried to export it with the main class used for the router (export {playeco, playStatsEco};) it showed me an error : "Attempted import error: './components/quiz/playeco' does not contain a default export (imported as 'playeco')."

Comment: Rather than asking a general "how do I" question, show the code that is causing the issue along with the error message **in the question content** .where it can be properly formatted and read easily by all. You can edit the question any time to add such clarifications. Also take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Much better. That's how it works here...show us the actual code problem. Not showing any export or import statements though

Comment: @charlietfl I've just added the error

Comment: Great, welcome to SO....new learning session on how to ask code related questions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export them:

```
export const playerStatsEco = {...}

export class playeco extends Component {...}
```

then you can import them from outside like that :

```
 import {playerStatsEco, playeco } from "./fileWhereConstDeclared"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export your consts and import them from different files.

```
 // In file where constant declared
 export const myConst = "some value";

 //In imported file
 import {myConst} from "./fileWhereConstDeclared"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this case, how can I export the class existing in the same file as well ? I tried : export {myClass, myConst}; but didn't work